# show html frame when by pass the login page where the frame reside

Tags: html, jsp

On siteA, it has a login page (loginframe.jsp) that is enclosed in a frameset: like below:

```
<frameset rows="39px,*" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="myAccountTopFrame.jsp" name="top" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" >
    <frame src="login2.jsp" name="bottom" frameborder="0" >
</frameset>
```

On siteB, it has an app that allows user to access siteA without manually perform the  login.  It basically does a form action post to siteA with userID and password embeded in the form.  It takes user directly to siteA main menu without problem, except that the frame is missing.  This is because it is not coming thru the login page.  Is there a way to do a post and make the response be the src of a frame? ==>

make this

```
<frame src="login2.jsp" name="bottom" frameborder="0" >
```

become

```
<frame src="response of a post" name="bottom" frameborder="0" >
```

Below is what the siteB form post looks like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name=LOGIN action="http://siteA/autoLogin"" method=POST>
            <input type=hidden name="LoginName" value="<%=myacct.getLoginName()%>">
            <input type=hidden name="Password" value="<%=myacct.getPassword()%>">
        </form>
        <script language=javascript>
            document.forms[0].submit();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: both siteA and siteB uses jsp view technology.

Comment: `Everything works fine except that the frame is missing.` **which one is missing** ?

Comment: To access siteA login page, user does https://siteA/loginframe.jsp.  This jsp uses frameset, where the actual login page is login2.jsp => <frame src="login2.jsp" name="bottom" frameborder="0" > (see the first section of code). On siteB, it is doing a form post to /autologin to directly take user into siteA's main menu.  Since it is not accessing loginframe.jsp, when user is taken to the main menu, the frame is missing.